# Animating a 3D vector

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d, matplotlib-animation, matplotlib-3d

I need to animate both the magnitude and the position of a vector arrow in a 3D figure with matplotlib. As far as I can tell, I cannot animate the position of the vectors with Axes3D.quiver and there is no matplotlib.pyplot.arrow for a 3D figure. Is there a way to do this or do I need to look at other options?

Comment: I can't tell what you are trying to achieve from your question. Can you put some relevant code and (if possible) pictures of what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`quiver` does not have an updating function, but you can easily remove an old quiver and plot a new one in each frame.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw=dict(projection="3d"))

def get_arrow(theta):
    x = np.cos(theta)
    y = np.sin(theta)
    z = 0
    u = np.sin(2*theta)
    v = np.sin(3*theta)
    w = np.cos(3*theta)
    return x,y,z,u,v,w

quiver = ax.quiver(*get_arrow(0))

ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_zlim(-2, 2)

def update(theta):
    global quiver
    quiver.remove()
    quiver = ax.quiver(*get_arrow(theta))

ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,200), interval=50)
plt.show()
```

[image: quiver animation]

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your own arrow similar to how `Axes3D.quiver` does, and change the line positions appropriately. Here is an idea how that could work:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def move_arrow(pos, dir, trunk_plt, head_plt, length=1, arrow_length_ratio=0.3, normalize=False, arrow_angle=15):
    pos = np.asarray(pos)
    dir = np.asarray(dir)
    dir_norm = dir / np.linalg.norm(dir)
    if normalize:
        dir = dir_norm
    shift = dir * length
    end = pos + shift
    # Make rotation matrix for arrow direction
    head_x = -dir_norm
    head_y = np.cross(head_x, np.arange(3) == head_x.argmin())
    head_z = np.cross(head_x, head_y)
    rot_ref = np.stack([head_x, head_y, head_z], axis=1)
    # Make rotation matrix for head tips
    arrow_rad = np.deg2rad(arrow_angle)
    s, c = np.sin(arrow_rad), np.cos(arrow_rad)
    rot_arrow = np.array([[c, 0, s], [0, 1, 0], [-s, 0, c]])
    # Compute head tips
    head_length = np.linalg.norm(shift) * arrow_length_ratio
    head_1 = end + rot_ref @ rot_arrow @ [head_length, 0, 0]
    head_2 = end + rot_ref @ rot_arrow.T @ [head_length, 0, 0]
    # Set line data
    trunk_plt.set_data([pos[0], end[0]], [pos[1], end[1]])
    trunk_plt.set_3d_properties([pos[2], end[2]])
    head_plt.set_data([head_1[0], end[0], head_2[0]], [head_1[1], end[1], head_2[1]])
    head_plt.set_3d_properties([head_1[2], end[2], head_2[2]])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
pos = [.2, .4, .1]
dir = [.5, .0, .3]
trunk_plt = ax.plot3D([], [], [], c='b')[0]
head_plt = ax.plot3D([], [], [], c='b')[0]
move_arrow(pos, dir, trunk_plt, head_plt)
ax.set_xlim(0, 1)
ax.set_ylim(0, 1)
ax.set_zlim(0, 1)
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')

def anim_frame(i):
    dir_shift = 0.1 * np.array([np.sin(0.01 * i + 1), np.sin(0.02 * i + 2), np.sin(0.03 * i + 3)])
    move_arrow(pos, dir + dir_shift, trunk_plt, head_plt)
    return [trunk_plt, head_plt]

anim = mplanim.FuncAnimation(fig, anim_frame, range(1000), interval=1. / 30., repeat=False, blit=True)
anim.save('arrow.avi')
```

Result:

[image: Arrow animation]